# Why won't my 2D movement work (Snake Game)

Tags: python, 2d

I can't for the life of me get the movement of my snake to work. Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random

#Functions
def player_animation():
    global player_speed_x, player_speed_y

    player.x += player_speed_x
    player.y += player_speed_y

    if player.top or player.left or player.right or player.bottom <=15:
        restart()
        player_speed_x, player_speed_y = 0, 0
    if player.top or player.left or player.right or player.bottom >=screen_width:
        restart()
        player_speed_x, player_speed_y = 0, 0
    if player.top or player.left or player.right or player.bottom >= screen_height:
        restart()
        player_speed_x, player_speed_y = 0, 0
    if player.colliderect(player):
        restart()
        player_speed_x, player_speed_y = 0, 0
    
    
    


def restart():
    global player_score

    player.center =(screen_width/2 -15, screen_height/2 -15)
    player_score = 0


def apple_function():
    global player_score

    if apple.colliderect(player):
        player_score +=1
        apple.random_x =(random.randint(15, screen_width -15))
        apple.random_y =(random.randint(15, screen_width -15))
    
    
    


pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

#Text Variables
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Game Variables
vel = 5
player_speed_x = 0
player_speed_y = 0
player_score = 0

#Screen Setup
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

#Apple Variables
apple_x = (random.randint(15, screen_width -15))
apple_y = (random.randint(15, screen_width -15))
    

#Game Rectangles
player = pygame.Rect(15, 15, 30, 30)
apple = pygame.Rect(apple_x, apple_y, 30, 30)


#Colours
bg_colour = pygame.Color("chartreuse2")
white = (255, 255, 255)
player_colour = (92, 130, 255)
apple_colour = (255, 46, 46)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed_y -= vel
                player_speed_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed_y +=vel
                player_speed_x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_speed_x -= vel
                player_speed_y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_speed_x += vel
                player_speed_y = 0

                
            




    #Drawn Elements
    screen.fill(bg_colour)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, apple_colour, apple)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_colour, player)

    #Functions
    #player_animation()
    apple_function()

    #Score Text
    score_text = font.render("Score: " + f"{player_score}", True, white)
    screen.blit(score_text, (15, 15))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried making different variables, and what I have now but none of it wants to work. Any help is appreciated :)

*Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details*
*Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details*
*Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details*
*Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details*
*Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlfow. "Filler Text because stackoverflow requires more details" Please do not do this. Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

Ignore this post! Figured it out. Just didn't have my player rectangle in my loop so it wouldn't update with they coordinates needed. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [answer], and do not use the answer section for this sort of commentary. If you wish to revoke a question, you may delete it. But above all else, note well that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.